# Swift: Render CALayers to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgcontext

I currently have a custom progress view in my application. I am attempting to draw the progress view and then take a "snapshot" of it so I can pass this along where needed. So once I have drawn my layers, I want to then convert them into a single UIImage.

Here is my current code, which also includes an attempt to save to the documents directory in order to view the image.

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)

        self.backgroundRingLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        self.progressRingLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
        let data:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData
        data.writeToFile(documentsDirectory, atomically: true)

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I am relatively new to using CGContext and such, so I may be way off with this. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do actually ? You have rendered to different CALayer into one single context, what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Just render the layer of the superview. It should include all subviews and sublayers.

```
self.view.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
```